# Fixed point free G-simplicial complex

Tags: simplicial-complex, equivariant-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $K$ be a finite abstract $G$-simplicial complex.  We say $K$ is fixed point free if for each $x$ in geometric realization of $K$, $||K||$, there exist a $g\in G$ such that $gx\neq x$. It is easy to check that if for every simplex $A\in K$ there exist a $g\in G$ such that $gA\neq A$, then $K$ is fixed point free.

I just wanted to know: Is there any necessary and sufficient conditions on $K$ for being fixed point free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you mentioned is both necessary and sufficient.  To see necessity, note that if $A\in K$ and $gA=A$, then $g$ fixes the barycenter of $A$ in the geometric realization.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the answer. I truly appreciate your help.